# File upload refresh issue Hayageek jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am using hayageek jquery file upload plugin with a form, the form is used for creating event sets. Each event set can have a maximum of 5 files. The form posts the data with an ajax call. When creating a new event set, the uploader throws the error "only 5 files are allowed", Since the files limit had been used for the previous set. So I am being forced to refresh the page each time to create a new event set. I want to reset the file uploader without a page refresh, don't know how to do this with this plugin. This is the code I am using:

```
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
         url: "upload.php",
             dragDrop: true,
             fileName: "myfile",
             returnType: "json",
             maxFileSize:1024*5120,
             maxFileCount:5,
             allowedTypes:"jpg,png,pdf",
             showDelete: true,
             deleteCallback: function (data, pd) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $.post("updel.php", {op: "delete",name: data[i]},
                    function (resp,textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //Show Message  
                    alert("File Deleted");
                   });           
                 }
              pd.statusbar.hide(); 
             }
     });
```

Can someone help me with this................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This workaround fixed my problem:

```
    var j=0;
$("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
            url: "upload.php",
                dragDrop: true,
                fileName: "myfile",
                returnType: "json",
                maxFileSize:1024*5120,
                // maxFileCount:5,
                allowedTypes:"jpg,png,pdf",
                showDelete: true,
                deleteCallback: function (data, pd) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $.post("updel.php", {op: "delete",name: data[i]},
                        function (resp,textStatus, jqXHR) {
                               //Show Message   
                               alert("File Deleted");
                               });
                        }
                        pd.statusbar.hide(); //You choice.
               },
               onSelect:function(files) {  
                    files[0].name;
                    files[0].size;
                alert(files.length);
                j=j+files.length;
                if(j<=5){
                         return true; //to allow file submission.
                }
           else {
          alert("limit exceeded");
          return false;
           }
            }
         });
```